# powershell- script with Activ Directory

Tags: powershell, csv

I created a script in powershell that give me a csv file from activ directory. 
And I have a 3 questions.

1. I want to remove all users that empty. like example: user1,
   class, room..  those user are not email address or last name.  I
   want to create a filter that remove this lines.
2. I want to add a few empty columns
3. to isolated a two word from long string.

this is the line that I wrote:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Sort-Object -Property SamAccountName  |Select GivenName , Surname, SamAccountName,OfficePhone, 
MobilePhone,EmailAddress, office, Department , Manager   |Export-csv c:\Test2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you want to do with the third question as you didn't provide any details or a before and after sample. As for 1. and 2., try this:

```
#Gets only required properties to increase performance
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties OfficePhone, MobilePhone, EmailAddress, Office, Department, Manager |
#Skip objects that's missing both surname and emailaddress
Where-Object { $_.EmailAddress -or $_.Surname } |
Sort-Object -Property SamAccountName |
#Added EmtpyColumn1 and EmptyColumn2 as empty strings, and extracts manager from manager DN-value.
Select GivenName , Surname, SamAccountName, OfficePhone, MobilePhone, EmailAddress, Office, Department , @{n="Manager";e={$_.Manager -replace 'CN=(.*?),.*', '$1'}}, @{n="EmptyColumn1";e={""}}, @{n="EmptyColumn1";e={""}} #|
#Added -NoTypeInformation to make it a valid CSV-file. Removes the #TYPE .... that's normally line 1 in the csv-file
Export-csv c:\Test2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thanks for your respond. 

1) It's work well:)
2) That add me a new column, but not empty: 
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection"
how I add a new empty column? 
3) I want to sparet the manager in my organization like this: 
CN=boaz avi,OU=Department name,DC=company name,DC=org,DC=il
I want that only :"boaz avi" will be in my line, without the rest..

Comment: Yeah, look at that. Usually you get a null-valued column, but I guess ADobjects in PowerShell dynamically creates properties when called, so you get a property-value property instead. Try updated answer.